# Where to put the customized functions for snippet?

Tags: emacs, elisp, yasnippet

I try to create a snippet which needs a little elisp code (about 15 lines). I don't want to put all the code there to make the snippet looks very ugly. A function call is the best choice. But I am not sure where should I put the code for that function.

For example: (Ugly)

${1: $(supper long elisp code here)}

I expect something like:

${1: $(my-function arg)}

Then where should I put my-function code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the code in your [initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). The function just needs to be defined before call `yas-expand`.

---

(Edited to include followup from comments.)

You can also create a .yas-snippet.el file in the same directory as the snippet with your function ([example](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/tree/master/prog-mode)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that. But what if I want to share the snippet with others? I can't share my init file to them. Do they have to copy the function to their init file? or Yasnippet provides more elegant way to do it.

Comment: You can also create a `.yas-snippet.el` file in the same directory as the snippet with your function ([example](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/tree/master/prog-mode)).

Comment: Hi Kyle. I have tried it and it works as expect. Would you please modify your answer by add the latest comment in it? Then I would mark it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: (example) link broken

Comment: It seems that the file name is now `.yas-setup.el` instead of `.yas-snippet.el`.